# Bidirectional UDP tunnel

Tags: sockets, networking, udp

Consider a `process A` which performs a bidirectional UDP communication with some `HOST` on a `PORT1`. Both `IP` and `PORT1` are configurable.  Moreover, `process A` binds to `PORT1`, I have no control over that.

Is it possible to create a UDP `tunnel` which routes the traffic of `process A` from `localhost` to `HOST`, i.e. so instead of the original

`process A <-> HOST:PORT1` we have a

`process A <-> localhost:PORT2 <-> tunnel <-> HOST:PORT1` type of communication?

The problem I'm facing is that both `process A` and `tunnel` bind to the same `localhost:PORT2` resulting in an `Address already in use` error.

Comment: why do you need to bind to port in a process A? just allow system to pick any available port for you. For tunnel you could use nginx : ```stream{server{ listen localhost:PORT2 udp; proxy_pass HOST:PORT1}}``` . I'm sure that there are multiple options to make UDP proxy beside nginx.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a UDP tunnel which routes the traffic of
>   process A from localhost to HOST

Certainly, you can write (or find) a program that receives UDP packets from one location and sends a copy of them to a second location (and vice versa).

> The problem I'm facing is that both process A and tunnel bind to the
>   same localhost:PORT2 resulting in an Address already in use error.

Your tunnel needs to bind to the port that process A is *sending packets to*, not to the port that process A is *receiving packets on*.  (presumably they are different ports, since if process A was binding its UDP socket to the same port it was sending UDP packets to, then it could only send UDP packets to itself, which wouldn't be a very useful thing to do)

Note that your remote program will need to be smart enough to send its UDP packets to the port that your tunnel-program is bound on rather than to the port that process A is bound on; otherwise the packets from the remote program will go straight to process A rather than through your tunnel-program.